# Hover effect doesn't work after slider toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have a table, where I change the color of the background, table etc. with a slider. The problem is, that when I turn the slider on or off, the hover effect of the table doesn't work anymore. I have tried it with a function but it only works, when the slider has not been used.

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards
Max

```js
function CheckSlider() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("colorSlider");

  if (slider.checked == true) {
    document.body.style.background = '#2e2e2e';
    ChangeTableColor('#2a0059', '#474747', 'white');
  } 
  else {
    document.body.style.background = 'whitesmoke';
    ChangeTableColor('blue', 'white', 'black');
  }
}

function ChangeTableColor(tableHeaderColor, tableDataColor, tableFontColor) {
  var tableHeader = document.getElementById('indexOverviewTable').getElementsByTagName('th');
  var tableData = document.getElementById('indexOverviewTable').getElementsByTagName('td');

  for (var i = 0; i < tableHeader.length; i++) {
    tableHeader[i].style.backgroundColor = tableHeaderColor;
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < tableData.length; j++) {
    tableData[j].style.backgroundColor = tableDataColor;
    tableData[j].style.color = tableFontColor;
  }
}
```

```css
#indexOverviewTable {
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-family: Cenury Gothic;
}

#indexOverviewTable th {
  background-color: #2a0059;
  color: white;
  font-size: 115%;
}

#indexOverviewTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #474747;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

#indexOverviewTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #696969;
  color: white;
}

#indexOverviewTable tr.header,
#indexOverviewTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #999999;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* only change below this line */

.slider:after {
  font-size: .8em;
  content: 'OFF';
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 34px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

input:checked+.slider:after {
  content: 'ON';
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="colorSlider" onclick="CheckSlider()">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<table class="table" id="indexOverviewTable" style="padding-top: 1em">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Stop setting inline styles (terrible!), toggle a class instead, and let your stylesheet do the rest,

Comment: It is going to take a long time to remove the style from the script/function and i am sure that is where the problem is as Biberman said use <style> for styling and give your function an id or class and if the style gets to long create a separate file/view for CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** You change the `tr` on `hover` but with your slider you change the `td`s. This way the `background-color` from the table row can't be visible after you gave the cells a `background-color` with the slider (initial is `inherit`). Therefor you should define the hover effect for the cells:

```css
#indexOverviewTable tr:hover td { ... }
```

Furthermore the CSS styles are overridden by the inline styles, that you set with JavaScript. Therefor you should define the styles with CSS for a class (maybe `body.dark`) and toggle that class with JavaScript.

CSS example:

```css
.dark #indexOverviewTable th {
  background-color: #2a0059;
}
```

By the way: The definition of a `background-color` for `#indexOverviewTable tr.header` isn't necessary because it isn't visible (in this example) - the `th`s are hiding it...

**Working example:** (*i removed :nth-child(even) and :nth-child(odd) for simplicity and because it was only one row*)

```js
function CheckSlider() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("colorSlider");

  if (slider.checked == true) {
    document.body.classList.add('dark');
  } 
  else {
    document.body.classList.remove('dark');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

#indexOverviewTable {
  padding-top: 1em;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-family: Cenury Gothic;
}

#indexOverviewTable th {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 115%;
}

.dark #indexOverviewTable th {
  background-color: #2a0059;
}

#indexOverviewTable td {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.dark #indexOverviewTable td {
  background-color: #474747;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

#indexOverviewTable tr:hover td {
  background-color: #999999;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* only change below this line */

.slider:after {
  font-size: .8em;
  content: 'OFF';
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 34px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

input:checked+.slider:after {
  content: 'ON';
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="colorSlider" onclick="CheckSlider()">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<table class="table" id="indexOverviewTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the **default** behavior. Fortunately it can be changed **just** with [CSS](//dev.mozilla.org/CSS).

Add the [`important`](//dev.mozilla.org/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception) rule to the [`hover`](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) style.

```
#indexOverviewTable tr.header,
#indexOverviewTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #999999 !important;
}
```

> Using !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with the !important rule are applied to the same element, the declaration with a greater specificity will be applied.
> <sub>**MDN Web Docs** | [Specifity](//dev.mozilla.org/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception)</sub>

---

There is another problem in your code. You style the [`tr`](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/HTML/Element/tr) element with [`hover`](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) but `tableData` is assigned to a [`td`](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/HTML/Element/td) element.

```
tableData = document.getElementById('indexOverviewTable').getElementsByTagName('td')
```

<sup>I recommend using [`querySelectorAll`](https://dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) as it is shorter.</sup>

```js
function CheckSlider() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("colorSlider");

  if (slider.checked == true) {
    document.body.style.background = '#2e2e2e';
    ChangeTableColor('#2a0059', '#474747', 'white');
  } 
  else {
    document.body.style.background = 'whitesmoke';
    ChangeTableColor('blue', 'white', 'black');
  }
}

function ChangeTableColor(tableHeaderColor, tableDataColor, tableFontColor) {
  var tableHeader = document.getElementById('indexOverviewTable').getElementsByTagName('th');
  var tableData = document.getElementById('indexOverviewTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');

  for (var i = 0; i < tableHeader.length; i++) {
    tableHeader[i].style.backgroundColor = tableHeaderColor;
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < tableData.length; j++) {
    tableData[j].style.backgroundColor = tableDataColor;
    tableData[j].style.color = tableFontColor;
  }
}
```

```css
#indexOverviewTable {
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-family: Cenury Gothic;
}

#indexOverviewTable th {
  background-color: #2a0059;
  color: white;
  font-size: 115%;
}

#indexOverviewTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #474747;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

#indexOverviewTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #696969;
  color: white;
}

#indexOverviewTable tr.header,
#indexOverviewTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #999999 !important;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* only change below this line */

.slider:after {
  font-size: .8em;
  content: 'OFF';
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 34px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

input:checked+.slider:after {
  content: 'ON';
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="colorSlider" onclick="CheckSlider()">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<table class="table" id="indexOverviewTable" style="padding-top: 1em">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[<kbd>Interactive Code</kbd>](//jsitor.com/8FGh7zA9D)

Comment: Wow, perfect. Thank you very much, you made my day.